# Can I redirect old URLs from an old CDN to new CDN?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cdn, shopify

I currently have a site setup using Shopify. We have employed the services of a web development company to build us a new website to replace our Shopify site.

The Shopify site contains MP3 downloads. These are linked directly to from a PDF we have already circulated to clients. Shopify has automatically hosted these files on a Content Delivery Network. The URLs for these look like this http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0058/7082/files/c_semi.mp3?316.

When we host our new website we will be provided with a new CDN as part of a package with our new hosting company.

We will have the ability to write a .htaccess file on this server, so I will redirect all our standard page URLs using 301 redirects.

So my question is, what about the files hosted on our Shopify CDN? They are linked to directly from other media so the URLs need to stay intact.

How can I redirect files with Shopify URLs like this http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0058/7082/files/c_semi.mp3?316 to the alternative on our new website?

Thanks in advance
-SWD

Comment: The requests for the mp3 files go to your old CDN, so only your old CDN can redirect them anywhere else. Rewriting on _your_ new server can not happen, because these requests do not even reach your new server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that once your shopify shop is closed; which I am assuming you'll do when the other website is ready to go live, your data will be removed, including the CDN data.

You may have to redirect via the shopify shop (keep it open for a while)

or

Use Google webmaster tools to redirect the url when it can't be found.

Comment: I assume that because the old CDN URLs are at http://cdn.shopify.com we are not the verified owners of that domain. So we wont be able to add the url redirects in our Google Webmaster account?